# Issue with custom rewrite for products and permalinks

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Not sure if I've done something incorrectly here, but I have the following rewrite rule;

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
    '^product/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?name=productl&id=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

Which seems to work; so if I visit the following URL

```
mysite.com/product/23/product-description-goes-here
```

a page loads. However, because the wordpress permalinks are enabled, it then seems to be getting rewritten again (?) to be the post title. So the resulting URL in my address bar is

```
mysite.com/product/
```

this of course is breaking the page as the id is no longer 
in the URL. How can I have it maintain my original URL and not rewrite it to be the pages post title?

Comment: What is your rule supposed to be loading- a page? A custom post type? What is `productl` and what does `id` belong to?

Comment: Hi Milo thanks for the response. 'product' (typo) is the name of a page I've created in wordpress. Inside the content of that page there is a shortcode which uses the id in the querystring parameter to fetch some data from an API

Comment: I seem to have got it working now. I think all I needed to do was change ?name= to ?pagename=  !